# Big Oh complexity of polynomial times log N

Tags: big-o

I understand O(NlgN) is linearithmic. But what is O(N^m(lgN))? Would is just be considered polynomial running time since the polynomial part grows faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the asymptotic behaviour of a function or algorithm can be described by `O(n^m log N)`, you should probably stick with just that. However, you could naturally say that *one* upper bound on the time complexity of that same function/algorithm is one of polynomial time, i.e.:

[image]

This is acceptable as the Big-O upper bound on the asymptotic behaviour mustn't necessarily be a tight one.

Now, let's say you have some algorithm and have found an upper asymptotic bound on it as `O(N^(m+1))`, but know that you used quite coarse tools when deriving this bound; i.e., possibly there exists tighter asymptotic bounds. However, before proceeding on a crusade in calculus and analysis, you could ask yourself: is this bound good enough for my purposes? (E.g. making sure the algorithm doesn't run in exponential time). If so, just use the so-so but acceptable bound you've derived.

In case you've already derived a tighter better bound, however, it is probably most favourable to stick with that bound when presenting the asymptotic behaviour of your function or algorithm.